# execute python scripts from html

Tags: python, html, cgi

The browser shows the code instead of running the python script.

The HTML code is as below:

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/static/savefiles.py" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
</body></html>
```

The Python code is as below:

```
#!c:\Python27\python.exe
#!/usr/bin/python


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()



        try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
            import msvcrt
            msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
            msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
        except ImportError:
            pass

        form = cgi.FieldStorage()

        # A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
        fileitem = form['file']

        # Test if the file was uploaded
        if fileitem.filename:

           # strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
           fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
           open(os.path.join('static/files/' + fn, 'wb')).write(fileitem.file.read())
           message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

        else:
           message = 'No file was uploaded'

        print """\
        Content-Type: text/html\n
        <html><body>
        <p>%s</p>
        </body></html>
        """ % (message,)
```

I have tried a variety of solutions posted on on the forum but none of them worked in my case. Please guide me on what needs to be corrected. Thanks all for your quick help.

Comment: What kind of web server are you using? I think you'll have to configure it to mark the folder with your Python script as cgi-bin

Comment: I am deploying this code on google app engine. I am very new to Python and helping a colleague who is on emergency leave. Could you please explain what exactly should I do.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled with this question and I have the same problem. Do you have the answer for this now?

As to why your code is not working is because HTML is not interpreting it as a python file. This is as much as I understand so far because I have yet to solve my problem. you need some sort of interpreter for html to understand a python file.